# grub2 problems in linux and windows

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, 17.04

GRUB2 version is: v2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.

When I select `ubuntu` in load menu, it gives following error and then proceeds with loading Ubuntu:

```
error: no symbol table.
Press any key to continue...
```

When I try to load Windows, it shows following and boot fails (returns to GRUB's boot menu):

```
error: symbol `grub_fshelp_find_file_lookup' not found    
error: no such device: 3C66-1611.    
Setting partition type to 0x83    
error: invalid signature    
Press any key to continue...
```

I have checked, the '3C66-1611' is the correct existing UUID of a bootbale partiotion of a disk, where loader of Windows OS is located, it is `/dev/sdc1` for gparted, and it is very strange that loader does not see it.

I tried to re-install the GRUB, but it does not help.

Please, tell me, how can load Windows. Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58056/discussion-on-question-by-username-grub2-problems-in-linux-and-windows).

Answer (score -1):

tl;dr: update your grup installtion at MBR or EFI or make sure it is at least on the same version than your grub files in /boot.

Just had the same problem

`` error: symbol `grub_fshelp_find_file_lookup' not found ``

this tells you: your grub installation at the mbr or within EFI is outdated and does not match the new modules in /boot.

in my case, i have a Acer Aspire V3-372 Notebook that refused to boot anything other than /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi, no matter how i changed the EFI settings. So i had manually replaced this by the /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi binary. After upgrading from jessie to stretch, i had to copy grup over again.

Comment: Acer is unique and requires the user to set an UEFI password and enable "trust" on the ubuntu/grub .efi boot files from within UEFI. Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291335&p=13341757#post13341757 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot